# Wordpress add_options_page() function not considering role

Tags: admin-menu

I am new to WordPress plugin development and i am stuck at why the wordpress function `add_options_page()` is not accepting role.

This is my code which is not working

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'ct_admin_settings_page');
function ct_admin_settings_page()
{
    add_options_page(
        'CT Settings',
        'CT Settings',
        'Administrator',
        'ct_admin_settings',
        'ct_admin_settings_page'
    );
}
```

but if i try the following, the menu appears (changing **Administrator** to **manage_options**),

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'ct_admin_settings_page');
function ct_admin_settings_page()
{
    add_options_page(
        'CT Settings',
        'CT Settings',
        'manage_options',
        'ct_admin_settings',
        'ct_admin_settings_page'
    );
}
```

It is my understanding that the third parameter in function `add_options_page` is [ROLE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) so why Administrator which is a ROLE not being accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect. The third parameter to the `add_options_page()` function is  Capability, not Role.

This is made clear by the function's prototype:

`function add_options_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function = '' )`

`manage_options` is a Capability. `Administrator` is not.

Comment: In practice capability checks ([`current_user_can()`](http://queryposts.com/function/current_user_can/)) in WP accept roles too. The actual issue here is case sensitivity, `administrator` would work.

Answer (score 1):

While WP commonly accepts roles in capability checks (notably often recommended against) it is case-sensitive and should be in lowercase:

```
var_dump( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ); // bool(true)
var_dump( current_user_can( 'Administrator' ) ); // bool(false)
```